# Get only processes of certain name/id in SOQL?

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have following SOQL query:

```
[SELECT p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem p WHERE p.ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending' AND p.ProcessInstance.TargetObject.Type = 'Contact' AND ActorId =: uid LIMIT 1];
```

With this I am getting one process which can be of any type... But I want it to filter for either the process id or the process name. Like `WHERE ProcessInstance.ProcessName = 'myName'`. Is this somehow possible? I didn't find anything which represents the name of the approval process.

Comment: [ProcessInstance](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_processinstance.htm) doesn't have a Name field. Do you want the [ProcessDefinition](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_processdefinition.htm) Name field?

Comment: Oh yeah, that would be awesome! Can I get the processdefinition from ProcessInstance or ProcessInstanceWorkitem somehow?

Comment: I don't have those objects setup in my org. However, try something like `SELECT p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem p WHERE p.ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending' AND p.ProcessInstance.TargetObject.Type = 'Contact' AND ActorId =: uid AND p.ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.Name = 'myName' LIMIT 1`